# How to migrate datasource from jboss standalone.xml to tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, jboss7.x

How do I migrate the datasource from standalone.xml to tomcat9.0.10.
I have added the below entry in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml
`

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DataSource" 
              global="jdbc/DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"              
              username="username"
              password="password"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.nonxa"
              description="JCG Example MySQL database."
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.13.253.129:1521:pe"
              maxTotal="10"
              maxIdle="10"
              maxWaitMillis="10000"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="300"            
              defaultAutoCommit="true" />
```

and ,I placed jdbc jar inside $CATALINA_HOME/lib directory,but it throws error  NoClassDefFound Exception.How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you driver class name is not valid , specify `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`as driverClassName.